# Is it possible to use a for loop for DRY protractor test? *var coming up undefined*

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor, angularjs-e2e

**Goal:**  I want to make make a loop over an `it` block that tests if an element text matches.

**Error:** `Error: No element found using locator: by.cssContainingText(".submenu li a", "undefined")`

**Question:**  How do I write a for loop to test multiple list items'?  Moreover, How do i make `var title` visible to the inner `it block`

For this example: I have 2 test that I want to DRY up via a loop 
*this next test example is just psuedocode doesn't work working test below*.

```
var config = require('../../protractor.conf.js').config;

describe('this Homepage Body Tests', function(){

  browser.driver.get(config.homepageUrl);

  describe('sub navigation functionality', function () {
    //creates teh array of strings for this sample
    var title = ['find a store', 'clinic'];


    for(var i = 0; i < title.length; i++){

      it("should open find a" + title[i] + "page", function(){

        browser.driver.sleep(2000);
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        var link = element(by.cssContainingText('.submenu li a', title[i]));
        expect(link.getText()).toEqual(title[i]);


      });
    };
 });

});
```

**HTML:**

```
  <div class="submenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a >find a store</a>
        </li>
        <li><a>clinic</a>
        </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
```

**Working Tests example:**

```
it("should open find a store page", function(){

  browser.driver.sleep(2000);
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

  var title = 'find a store';
  var link = element(by.cssContainingText('.submenu li a', title));


  expect(link.getText()).toEqual(title);


});

it("should open find a clinic page", function(){

  browser.driver.sleep(2000);
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

  var title = 'clinic';

  var link = element(by.cssContainingText('.submenu li a', title));


  expect(link.getText()).toEqual(title);


});
```

**Update:**

```
it("should open find a store page", function(){

      browser.driver.sleep(2000);
      browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

      var string = 'find a store';
      var main = '.main';
      var link = element(by.cssContainingText('.submenu li a', string));


      expect(link.getText()).toEqual(string);
      //I WANT OT CLICK ON THAT TOO!
      link.click().then(function() {

        browser.driver.sleep(3000);
        var title = element(by.cssContainingText(main, string));
        expect(title.getText()).toBe(string);
      });

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where [`element.all()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder) + [`map()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map) would help:

```
var titles = element.all(by.css('.submenu li a')).map(function (elm) {
    return elm.getText();
});

expect(titles).toBeArrayOfStrings();
expect(titles).toEqual(['find a store', 'clinic']);
```

FYI, here is the relevant feature request:

- [Add map() function to element.all](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/392)

Also see:

- [protractor - how to get the result of an array of promises into another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21736191/protractor-how-to-get-the-result-of-an-array-of-promises-into-another-array)
- [AngularJS + Protractor sum all row values in repeater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22806379/angularjs-protractor-sum-all-row-values-in-repeater)

Comment: Marked correct regardless.  I can make a new question if requested

Comment: @MatthewHarwood I'll be AFK for awhile, please ask a separate one, thanks. I'll check out the new question later anyway.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27258609/drying-up-protractor-clicks-tests-using-a-for-loops @alecxe